# Why doesn't a ListBox bound to an IEnumerable update?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have the following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListBoxTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Model />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button Content="Add" Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the following code for the `Model` class, which is put into main window's `DataContext`:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Model()
    {
        items = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    }

    public void AddItem()
    {
        items.Add(items.Count, items.Count.ToString());

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Items"));
    }

    private Dictionary<int, string> items;
    public IEnumerable<string> Items { get { return items.Values; } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

and main window's code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var model = this.DataContext as Model;
        model.AddItem();
    }
}
```

When pressing the button, the contents of the list are not being updated.

However, when I change the getter of the `Items` property to this:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Items { get { return items.Values.ToList(); } }
```

it starts to work.

Then, when I comment out the part which sends `PropertyChanged` event it stops working again, which suggests that the event is being sent correctly.

So if the list receives the event, why can't it update its contents correctly in the first version, without the `ToList` call?

Comment: Have you considered to use an ObservableCollection?

Comment: @heltonbiker It has serious drawbacks - like lack of `AddRange` and no other possibility to perform batch updates, which won't cause update on each added item. Also, I have a dictionary not a plain list.

Comment: @BartoszKP There are implementations of observable dictionaries available (just search for ObservableDictionary). You could bind the ItemsSource of the ListBox directly to an ObservableDictionary, and bind the ListBox items (in the ItemTemplate) to the `Value` property of a dictionary entry.

Comment: @Clemens I've found `ObservableDictionary` implementations, but I was a bit shocked that such a basic thing cannot be done with components provided by the library - very not .NET-like :) So I'm a bit reluctant to start downloading self-made framework extensions, until I'm absolutely sure that they are needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raising the `PropertyChanged` event for the `Items` property is only effective if the property value has actually changed. While you raise the event, the WPF binding infrastructure notices that the collection instance returned by the property getter is the same as before and does nothing do update the binding target.

However, when you return `items.Values.ToList()`, a new collection instance is created each time, and the binding target is updated.

Comment: Seems I've completely misunderstood what `PropertyChanged` is for :) This completely makes sense, in the context of what I was reading about the topic. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if it's precisely related, but sometimes calling `NotifyPropertyChanged(null)` (using null as argument instead of the property name), _every_ property on the screen is updated. It has solved some problems for me in the past.

Comment: @heltonbiker Even if you notify a change for all properties instead of a specific one, there wouldn't be an update of the binding target, as the source collection hasn't actually changed.